# Python Json Parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm having a bit of an issue with parsing json with python using the json library.
Here is the format of the json I'm trying to parse:

```
{'entry':[
    {

        JSON Data 1
    }, 

        JSON Data 2
    }
]}
```

And here is my Python:

```
for entry in response['entry'][0]:

    video['video_url'] = entry['id']['$t']
    video['published'] = entry['published']['$t']
```

I don't seem to be able to iterate over the two blocks of JSON with the above code, I only get the first block outputted for some reason.

Anybody have any ideas?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `{` in your JSON. (As if you'd be missing a bracket in Python.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

```
response = {'entry':[
    {

        JSON Data 1
    }, 
    {

        JSON Data 2
    }
]}
```

And:

```
response['entry'][0] == { JSON Data 1  }
```

Then:

```
for entry in response['entry']:

    video['video_url'] = entry['id']['$t']
    video['published'] = entry['published']['$t']
```

Or:

```
video = dict(zip(['video_url', 'published'], [entry['id']['$t'], entry['published']['$t']]) for entry in response['entry']
```

Comment: Nope, that only returns the first block :-/ Thanks for your help

Comment: response['entry'][0] == { JSON Data 1 }, {JSON Data 2}

Comment: Ok, than could you please give us your input in details so we will able to understand what you really need? response['entry'][0] == { JSON Data 1 }, {JSON Data 2} or response['entry'][0] == [{ JSON Data 1 }, {JSON Data 2}]?

Answer (score 1):

That list contains 2 separate dicts. Iterate over the list directly.

Comment: could you provide an example please?

Comment: `for foo in [1, 2, 3]: do_something(foo)`